# How to rerun and stop app script based on the execution log info?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I am looking to run below app script with multiple var url such as

```
https://www.testurl.com/link1=processing

https://www.testurl.com/link2=processing

https://www.testurl.com/link3=processing
```

How to add multiple url to below code:

```
function url() {
      var url = 'https://www.testurl.com/link1=processing';
    
      var options = {
        'method': 'get'
      };
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
      Logger.log(response);
    }
```

Each run with single url shows below execution log

```
3:33:30 AM  Notice  Execution started
3:33:31 AM  Info        {"status":200,"message":"Import 25 of 200 completed."}
3:33:31 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

I am looking to rerun script for first url till i get the log message containing "is not triggered" and then run second url and rerun till i get the log message containing "is not triggered" and then run third url and rerun till i get the log message containing "is not triggered" and then stop.

```
3:33:30 AM  Notice  Execution started
3:33:31 AM  Info        {"status":403,"message":"Import #16 is not triggered. Request skipped."}
3:33:31 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: It looks that you are making two questions in on one. Please narrow the question scope to ask a single question.

Comment: Your logic escapes me.  It is easy to loop through the urls and run them sequenctially.  Its easy, provide what you are saying is true, to continue to UrlFetchApp..fetch() until the "is not riggered" message occurs.  However what makes each call to fetch different to cause the message to change is unknwon and response doesn't contain any data so whay your doing with fetch is unknown to me.

Comment: @TheWizEd can you help with the code to make a sequential loop
its the cron i am trying to run with each url to import data in my website. When it runs it does not complete entirely (showing partial complete message "Import 25 of 200 completed") and requires rerun till all the import completes. Every run starts from where it stopped.

Comment: @TheWizEd Once all 200 completed for a url (with link1) it requires a separate trigger url to run the cron (for url with link1) from the start again and that is where "is not triggered" message occurs. Unless i dont run the separate trigger url manually the above cron (for url with link1) will keep showing "is not triggered" message. Once the "is not triggered" message occurs i want the script to move to next url and complete in similar way.

Comment: @TheWizEd I can get the process done by creating a time based trigger to run every minute but it does not have option to stop it once it is done and move to second url.

I hope i was able to explain properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is really no way for me to test this but I think it illustrates how this can be done:

```
function getUrls() {
  try {
    var urls = [ 'https://www.testurl.com/link1=processing',
                 'https://www.testurl.com/link2=processing',
                 'https://www.testurl.com/link3=processing' ];

    function getUrl(url) {
      var options = { 'method': 'get' };
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
      while( response.message.indexOf("is not triggered") < 0 ) {
        Logger.log(response);
        response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
      }
    }

    urls.forEach( getUrl );
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for code. Got the loop working.
But i am getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined"
what can be the issue here. And does index0f search for the exact term ("is not triggered")within the log statement/sentence

Comment: Per your description the message "is not triggered" is in the response of your fetch(). and stops the loop.  Perhaps if the fetch() fails or is complete it return undefined?  Test the value of response each time.

Comment: thanks got it solved